# How to display Multiple data into a single column in Antd Table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

So I want to show multiple data in a single cell of an ant design table. Seems it allows only to insertion of a single data element. Is that possible to combine multiple data into a single cell?

here is what the data object looks like:

```
data {
    transactionNo
    transactionTypeNo
    transactionType
    createdTstamp
    sourceNo
    accountNo
    currencyCd
    
  }
```

These are the table columns

```
const columns = [
{
  title: 'Transaction No',
  dataIndex: 'transactionNo',
  key: 'transactionNo',
  align: 'left',
  },
},
{
  title: 'Transaction Date',
  dataIndex: 'createdTstamp',
  defaultSortOrder: DESC,
  sortable: true,
  key: 'createdTstamp',
},
{
  title: 'Description',
  dataIndex: 'transactionType',
  key: 'transactionType',
  align: 'left',
  textWrap: 'wrap',
  defaultHidden: false,
  render: ( record) => (
    <>{record.transactionType}</>
  ),
},
```

I want to show both **transactionType** and **sourceNo** in a single cell.
Already tried using record but no luck. And I'm using react with typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Render Method in the antd Columns. You have found almost, just need to reference the record correctly..

```
{
  title: 'Description',
  dataIndex: 'transactionType',
  key: 'transactionType',
  align: 'left',
  textWrap: 'wrap',
  defaultHidden: false,
  // in Render first param returns current field, second params return entire data
  render: (text, record) => (
    <>{record.transactionType} {record.sourceNo}</>
  ),
},
```

Comment: `render: (text: string, record: any) => ( )`
used 'any' with the record because I'm using typescript and it worked. will this cause any problems?

Comment: no.. but you can use the same interface or type used for the table data in the record.